# How to use ImageBackground to set background image for screen in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, imagebackground

When I use  in react-native it gives warning that using  with children is deprecated and will be error in future. User  instead.

So,
If I use  it doesn't give expected result which I was getting using

Here is the code I wrote for using

```
<ImageBackground source={require('../../img/splash/splash_bg.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage} >
        </ImageBackground>
```

And style code is

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    // width: undefined,
    // height: undefined,
    // flexDirection: 'column',
    // backgroundColor:'transparent',
    // justifyContent: 'flex-start',


},}
```

[image: Expected result: getting when using <Image>]
[image: Result using <ImageBackground>]

Comment: Per https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/dc97e3fb4e1a297d18b9361710290468060626fc/Libraries/Image/ImageBackground.js, ImageBackground accepts two style props – style and imageStyle – which are (obviously) applied to the internal View and Image respectively. It's also worth noting that height and weight values from the container style are applied to the image style automatically.

Comment: I have tried using only <ImageBackground> Without any parent or children but still not able to get expected result.

Answer (score 75):

You can use ["ImageBackground"](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting) component on React Native.

```
<ImageBackground
  source={yourSourceFile}
  style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
> 
    <....yourContent...>
</ImageBackground>
```

Comment: I don't know if it is weird or not, but it would only give me an error if I did not specify 'width' and 'height' attributes, and I did not see this documented anywhere. Your answer made me find out what was wrong :D

Comment: Not upvoting to preserve number but this works for me.

Answer (score 23):

i achieved this by:

```
import { ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

<ImageBackground style={ styles.imgBackground } 
                 resizeMode='cover' 
                 source={require('./Your/Path.png')}>

   //place your now nested component JSX code here

</ImageBackground>
```

And then the Styles:

```
imgBackground: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        flex: 1 
},
```

Comment: import { ImageBackground ] from 'react-native'; should change ] to } right?

Answer (score 5):

Two options:

1. Try setting width and height to width and height of the device screen
2. Good old position absolute

Code for #2:

```
 render(){
    return(
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
           <Image style={{ width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight, position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0 }}/>
           <Text>Hey look, image background</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

**Edit**:
For option #2 you can experiment with `resizeMode="stretch|cover"`

**Edit 2**: 
Keep in mind that option #2 renders the image and then everything after that in this order, which means that some pixels are rendered twice, this might have a very small performance impact (usually unnoticeable) but just for your information

Answer (score 3):

[ImageBackground](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting) is a very simple and useful component.Put your component inside `ImageBackground` as a nested component and tweak a position of your component by using `position`.

Here's an example.

```js
<ImageBackground
  source={{ uri: hoge }}
  style={{
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    position: 'relative', 
    top: 0,
    left: 0
  }}
>
  <Text
    style={{
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: 'white',
      position: 'absolute', 
      bottom: 0, 
      left: 0
    }}
  >
    Hello World
  </Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to the RN docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images

> A common feature request from developers familiar with the web is background-image. To handle this use case, you can use the `<ImageBackground>` component, which has the same props as `<Image>`, and add whatever children to it you would like to layer on top of it.

You might not want to use `<ImageBackground>` in some cases, since the implementation is very simple. Refer to `<ImageBackground>`'s source code for more insight, and create your own custom component when needed.

```
return (
  <ImageBackground source={require('./image.png')} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
    <Text>Inside</Text>
  </ImageBackground>
);
```

Note that you must specify some width and height style attributes.

Note also that the file path is relative to the directory the component is in.

Comment: I Set Background image like you. But If i add <ScrollView> inside <ImageBackground>, i can't scroll down beyond the screen size. Please refer my image https://imgur.com/xP0LCFL

Answer (score 1):

```
     <ImageBackground
            source={require("../assests/background_image.jpg")}
            style={styles.container}

        >
            <View
                style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center"
                }}
            >
                <Button
                    onPress={() => this.props.showImagePickerComponent(this.props.navigation)}
                    title="START"
                    color="#841584"
                    accessibilityLabel="Increase Count"
                />
            </View>
        </ImageBackground>
```

Please use this code for set background image in react native

Comment: container: {
        flex: 1,
        //justifyContent: "center",
        //alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
    },

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
const img = '../../img/splash/splash_bg.png';
<ImageBackground  source={{ uri: img }} style={styles.backgroundImage} >
    </ImageBackground>
```

This worked for me.
Reference to RN docs can be found here.I wrote mine by reading this-
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting

Answer (score 1):

To add background Image, React Native is based on component, the *ImageBackground* Component requires two props *style={{}}* and *source={require('')}*

```
 <ImageBackground source={require('./wallpaper.jpg')} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}> 
<....yourContent Goes here...>
    </ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was searching Google on how to achieve this in 2021, so I will go ahead and add how I achieved this. NOTE: I am using `styled-components` in my project. Another thing to mention is that you might not need the additional `View` component, but I am using the `SafeAreaView` component inside of the `Background` component to add the additional spacing below the status bar for iOS.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Background = styled.ImageBackground`
  flex: 1;
  resize-mode: cover; // Not sure if this helps, but it was used in the docs, listed below
  justify-content: center;
`;

const Container = styled.SafeAreaView`
  flex: 1;
`;

...
return (
  <Background source={require('../assets/image.png')}>
    <Container>
      // rest of your components
    </Container>
  </Background>
)
...
```

[docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground)

Answer (score 0):

```
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')


<View style={{marginBottom: 20}}>
   <Image 
        style={{ height: 200, width: width, position: 'absolute', resizeMode: 'cover' }}
        source={{ uri: 'https://picsum.photos/'+width+'/200/?random' }}
                />
   <View style={styles.productBar}>
       <View style={styles.productElement}>
            <Image
                  style={{ height: 160, width: width - 250, position: 'relative', resizeMode: 'cover' }}
                  source={{ uri: 'https://picsum.photos/'+ 250 +'/160/?random' }}
                        />
       </View>
       <View style={styles.productElement}>
             <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, paddingLeft: 20 }}>Başlık</Text>
             <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, paddingLeft: 20, color: "blue"}}>Alt Başlık</Text>
       </View>
   </View>
</View>



 productBar: {
    margin: 20,
    marginBottom: 0,
    justifyContent: "flex-start" , 
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  productElement: {
    marginBottom: 0, 
 },
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help u..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { homePageStyles } from '../styles/Style';
import { Text, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import HomePageWallpaper from '../images/homePageWallpaper.jpg';

export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ImageBackground source={HomePageWallpaper} style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', width: null, height: null }}>
                <Container>                    
                    <Content>
                        <Text style={homePageStyles.description_text}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</Text>
                    </Content>
                </Container >
            </ImageBackground>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem with background image and its child components including logo images.
After wasting few hours, I found the correct way to solve this problem.
This is surely helped to you.

```
var {View, Text, Image, ImageBackground} = require('react-native');
import Images from '@assets';

export default class Welcome extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ImageBackground source={Images.main_bg} style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.markWrap}>
                    <Image source={Images.main_logo} 
                    style={styles.mark} resizeMode="contain" />
                </View>
                <View style={[styles.wrapper]}>
                    {//Here put your other components}
                </View>              
                
            </ImageBackground>
        );
    }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,
    },
    markWrap: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 83,
        borderWidth:1, borderColor: "green"
      },
    mark: {
        width: null,
        height: null,
        flex: 1,
    },
    wrapper:{
        borderWidth:1, borderColor: "green",///for debug
        flex: 1,
        position:"relative",
    },
}
```

[Logo on background Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk0nR.jpg)

(PS: I put on the dummy image on this screen instead of real company logo.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to import background component first to use backgroundimage on your code

Answer (score 0):

`<ImageBackground source=require('../../img/splash/splash_bg.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage} />`

Use `resizeMode: "contain"` Resize the background image to make sure the image is fully visible and `resizeMode: "cover"` Resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

 carImage: {
   width: "100%",
   height: "100%",
   resizeMode: "cover"
 }
})
```

Answer (score -7):

```
.hero-image {
  background-image: url("photographer.jpg"); /* The image used */
  background-color: #cccccc; /* Used if the image is unavailable */
  height: 500px; /* You must set a specified height */
  background-position: center; /* Center the image */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
  background-size: cover; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */
}
```

[look result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP0Ci.png)